# Entity Framework TPH creating multiple ID columns

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have the following:

```
class Employee {
 [Key]
 public int EmployeeID {get;set;}
 public List<TimeSensitiveData> JobTitle {get;set;}
 public List<TimeSensitiveData> Department {get;set;}
 public List<TimeSensitiveData> OfficeLocation {get;set;}
}

abstract class TimeSensitiveData {
 [Key]
 public int TimeSensitiveDataID {get;set;}
 public string Value1 {get;set;}
 public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}

class JobTitle : TimeSensitiveData {}
class Department : TimeSensitiveData {}
class OfficeLocation : TimeSensitiveData {}
```

seed method looks something like this:

```
seed () {
 List<TimeSeriesData> oflc = new List<TimeSeriesData>();
            TimeSeriesData oflc2 = new OfficeLocation();
            oflc2.Value1 = "New York";
            oflc.Add(oflc2); 
 List<TimeSeriesData> dpt = new List<TimeSeriesData>();
            TimeSeriesData dpt2 = new Department();
            dpt2.Value1 = "New York";
            dpt.Add(dpt2); 
  List<TimeSeriesData> jt = new List<TimeSeriesData>();
            TimeSeriesData jt2 = new JobTitle();
            jt2.Value1 = "New York";
            jt.Add(jt2);

 var Employees = new List<Employee> {
  new Employee{JobTitle=jt,Department=dpt,OfficeLocation=oflc},

 } 

}
```

when I seed the database with employees it creates an employees table and a TimeSensitiveData table. In the TimeSensitiveData table there is a Discriminator column (which I know what it's doing) but there are also multiple Employee_EmployeeID columns. Actually, it seems like its creating one for every complex object that extends TimeSensitiveData.

so the TimeSensitiveData table looks kind of like this

```
TimeSensitiveDataID  Value1  Date  Discriminator  Employee_EmployeeID Employee_EmployeeID1 Employee_EmployeeID2
1                    xx      date  JobTitle       NULL                NULL(or value)       NULL
2
etc..
etc..
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, any ideas?

should I make the Lists in the employee model not TimeSensitiveData type lists? should they be concrete class type lists?

Comment: Do you have any other fluent configuration of your entities? does it still do this if you mark the `TimeSensitiveDataID` column with `[Key]` attribute?

Comment: @DavidG yea I actually already have the [Key] attribute set, same issue, I'll update question

Comment: @DavidG actually, the model is off, let me update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[InverseProperty] fixed it partially